# validate group by duplicate textbox value in javascript on textboxt onblur

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, duplicates

validate first column group by not enter duplicate in second column textbox in javascript on textboxt onblur

```html
    <table rules="all" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>1</span><input name="SerialNo1" type="text" value="5">
                </td>
                <td><input name="SerialNo_1" type="text" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>2</span><input name="SerialNo2" type="text" value="5">
                </td>
                <td><input name="SerialNo_2" type="text" value="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>3</span><input name="SerialNo3" type="text" value="5">
                </td>
                <td><input name="SerialNo_3" type="text" value="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>4</span><input name="SerialNo4" type="text" value="9">
                </td>
                <td><input name="SerialNo_4" type="text" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>5</span><input name="SerialNo5" type="text" value="9">
                </td>
                <td><input name="SerialNo_5" type="text" value="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span>6</span><input name="SerialNo6" type="text" value="10">
                </td>
                <td><input name="SerialNo_6" type="text" value="1"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It show be result like below. This is after validate. 
[image: Like below]

Validate duplicate entry in second column textbox group by first column textbox.
Please guide me

Comment: I don't see any question...

Comment: Is this a "How to validate..." question? I cannot follow your explanation.

Comment: @JacobBarnes Yes I want to validate second column textbox according to first column textbox group by.

Comment: Validate how? If Col1 = Col2 throw error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic example of how you would use a `blur` listener.  Here I put one on all of the `inputs` and it will look for the other `input` in its row (`tr`):

```
var input1 = tr.children[0].children[1];
var input2 = tr.children[1].children[0];
```

Then, check if the values are the same or not (green if true, red if false)

```
tr.style.backgroundColor = input1.value === input2.value ? 'green' : 'red';
```

```js
var tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener('blur', function(evt) {
    var index = evt.target.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
    var tr = tbody.children[index]
    var input1 = tr.children[0].children[1];
    var input2 = tr.children[1].children[0];
    tr.style.backgroundColor = input1.value === input2.value ? 'green' : 'red';
  });
}
```

```html
<table rules="all" class="table table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>1</span> <input name="SerialNo1" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td> <input name="SerialNo_1" type="text" value="1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>2</span> <input name="SerialNo2" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td> <input name="SerialNo_2" type="text" value="2"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>3</span> <input name="SerialNo3" type="text" value="5">
      </td>
      <td> <input name="SerialNo_3" type="text" value="3"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>4</span> <input name="SerialNo4" type="text" value="9">
      </td>
      <td> <input name="SerialNo_4" type="text" value="1"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>5</span> <input name="SerialNo5" type="text" value="9">
      </td>
      <td> <input name="SerialNo_5" type="text" value="2"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <span>6</span> <input name="SerialNo6" type="text" value="10">
      </td>
      <td> <input name="SerialNo_6" type="text" value="1"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is a very simple implementation and shouldn't be used, this just demonstrates the idea of blur.** The way in which the inputs are linked is not very robust (if the html changes at all, this breaks).  It would be better to have a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) or a function that assigns these listeners when each input is created (if dynamically created).